# my website get an file error when i submit

Tags: javascript, html

the only problem i have now is i cant save my save my text in text field:

i have tried with java script, i dont know if this can work.

if you have an idea what i can do, it will be nice.

but i think that i have fixed the problem with the file error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>

        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#eoe1e2" align="center">
            <table id="table-text" align="center" border="0" width="100%" height="700px">
                <tr height="10px">
                    <td align="center"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">

                        <!-- BEGIN MAIN SECTION -->
                        <!----    BEGIN MAIN BODY OF PAGE   ---->
                        <table align="center" border="0" width="80%">
                            <tr><td align=center>&#160;</td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="center">

                                    <form name='plugstatus' action='file:///C:/Users/mib/Desktop/sss.HTML' method='POST' id='plug_form'>
                                        <table border=2 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan='8' align='center'><b>PLUG CONTROL</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan='8' align='center'><b>Unit LOCAL</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor='#cfcfcf'>
                                                <td valign='top'>PLUG</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>NAME</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>DEFAULT</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>BOOT/SEQ.<br />DELAY</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>STATUS</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>PRIORITY</td>
                                                <td valign='top'>ACTION</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>


                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf'>A1</td>
                                                <td align='left' bgcolor='#cfcfcf'>
                                                    <input type="text" name="txtfield" id="txtfield" value=""
                                                           placeholder="input your text" onchange="storeitem(this.value)" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf' align='center'>OFF</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf' align='center'>0.5 Secs</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf' align='center'>OFF</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf' align='center'>
                                                    1

                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#cfcfcf' align='center'>
                                                    <select name="u1plug1"><option value='0'>On</option><option value='2'>Off</select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                ¨
                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef'>A2</td>
                                                <td align='left' bgcolor='#efefef'>BDK-ASR1002_RACK04</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef' align='center'>OFF</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef' align='center'>0.5 Secs</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef' align='center'>OFF</td>
                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef' align='center'>2</td>


                                                <td bgcolor='#efefef' align='center'><select name="u1plug2"><option value='0'>On</option><option value='2'>Off</option></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>


                                        </table>



                                        <script language="javascript">
                                            function storeitem(val) {
                                                localStorage.setItem('txtfield', val)
                                            }

                                            function loaditem() {

                                                var txtfield = document.getElementById('txtfield');
                                                txtfield.value = localStorage.getItem('txtfield');

                                            }

                                            window.onload = loaditem;
                                        </script>

    <h1>  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not to mention that you html is entirely invalid. You might want to look into some basic HTML tutorials before starting with javascript and jquery.

Comment: Are you loading this HTML page from a webserver or from a local disk?

Comment: @Mikkel: Your edit changed the question into a completely different question, making the answers invalid. Instead of editing your question so drastically you should accept an answer that solves the problem at hand and then create a new question with your new problem. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your HTML from a local disk and only provide `/cgi-bin/gethtml` as the action, the browser will try to find this path on your local disk to load it.

This path will almost certainly be invalid (unless you are using a unix based OS and actually created the path `/cgi-bin/`), so you'll get the error message.

To make this work you need to either add the complete URL as action:

```
http://server.whatever/cgi-bin/gethtml
```

or load your HTML via HTTP from the server, so the relative path works.

**Edit:**

The directory `/cgi-bin/` on a webserver has a special meaning, it contains scripts that are executed by the webserver, usually perl or similar scripting languages but they can also be binary programs.

These scripts/programs need to be executed by a webserver, they can't be used with `file://...` URIs. The same goes for evaluating form data.

Comment: The question has been edited to say `action='file:///C:/Users/mib/Desktop/sss.HTML'`. What this answer doesn't make clear is that if you want to do anything with submitted form data then you need a **server** side program to process it. You can't just stick a local file path in the form action.